# Squid3 dns resolution error

Tags: proxy, ipv6, squid

Squid3 on ubuntu 12.04 returns ipv6 addresses instead of ipv4. I have no ipv6 network therfeore connection fails. DNS resolution directly on the server returns ipv4 addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line in your squid.conf file:

```
dns_v4_first on
```